# How do I correctly use variables with sed?

Tags: sed

I need to use a string variable in a sed command. My attempt is given in script.sh, it does not do what I want, I assume because my variable contains characters that I need sed to evaluate. I am working in linux bash.

input.txt

```
delicious.banana
gross.apple
```

script.sh

```
adjectives="delicious\|gross\|bearable\|yummy"
sed "s/\($adjectives\)\.//g" input.txt > output.txt
```

output.txt desired

```
banana
apple
```

output.txt current

```
deliciousbanana
grossdapple
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-gnu `sed` don't work with `\|` in BRE (basic regex mode). I suggest using `ERE` (Extended regex mode) using `-E` and as a bonus you can eliminate all the **escaping**:

```bash
adjectives="delicious|gross|bearable|yummy"
sed -E "s/($adjectives)\.//g" input.txt

banana
apple
```